# I have 2 files. Appsettings.config & Web.config. I want to use the appsettings value in the web.config file. Is it possible to do it?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, config

**Appsettings.config**

`<appsettings> <add key="ServerName" value="CURSE\SQL2019"/> <add key="Endpoint" value="C:\Test\Endpoint"/> </appsettings>`

**Web.config**

`<connectionStrings> <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="data source=*(want to use the ServerName key's value here)*;Initial Catalog=HPE_DEV;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> </connectionStrings>`

OR

`<appsettings> <endpoint address="(*Use the value of Endpoint key from appsettings.config*)" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Test" contract="TestService.TestService" name="TestService"/> </appsettings>`

Is this possible to do in Config files by using any variable or so?

I tried to Directly use Endpoint key in web.config but it did not worked.

`<appsettings> <endpoint address="Endpoint" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Test" contract="TestService.TestService" name="TestService"/> </appsettings>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to other configuration values in the configuration.

u can change the config file at runtime, if that is something you want
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878910/Change-config-File-at-Runtime-Csharp-Code